# Can I test if a battery is connected to a circuit?

Tags: voltage, batteries, pins

I have a 12 V rechargeable lead acid backup battery that is connected to a circuit. When the battery is not in use there is a constant 12 V applied for charging, and when the battery is in use there is still the 12 V at the input pin.

Is there any way of measuring whether the battery is connected, and if it is charging or discharging from the + pin of the battery? This all needs to be put into one circuit so anything bulky will not work.

[image]

Comment: You need to apply about 13.6 volts to keep a "12 volt" lead-acid battery near full charge. 12 volts will just keep it above "nearly dead".

Comment: It’s a Uninterupted power supply circuit (UPS) so it has a 12v input from the mains and 12v from a battery , there is also a constant 12v output, if there is a drop in mains voltage the circuit will switch to using the battery , I need a way to measure whether the battery is charging / discharging or not connected at all ? I will post a picture of the circuit I am using

Comment: It is not clear what we are allowed to do. There are current sensors that clamp around a wire. Maybe that would work for you. There are ways to sense current flowing into a circuit board, using a hall sensor (ACS711) or a current shunt (INA199). Please read about such things and see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: When a battery is connected to a circuit, the current that flows could be positive (Let's say that "positive" means the battery is discharging), or it could be negative (the battery is charging), or it could be zero. If your ammeter is very sensitive, then the probability of it reading exactly zero is small, but if both positive and negative are possibilities, then zero _must be_ a possibility. Zero also happens to be what the ammeter would read if the battery was disconnected. That means, you can't reliably test for "connectedness" by looking at the current alone.

Comment: Those two circuit boards look identical. :^)

Comment: @Transistor I played “spot the difference” for a good while before finally deciding that there was none. It would have been much more fun had there been one.

Answer (score 1):

A current measurement from one of the battery terminals would tell you if something is connected. This could be done with a multi meter or there are many other circuits and [devices](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=current%20battery%20measure%2012v&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=current%20battery%20measure) that can [measure current](https://www.google.com/search?q=measurement%20current%20battery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1). If the current is flowing into the battery then it is charging. If current is flowing out of the battery, there is something connected to it. If you measure no current, then nothing is on, or connected to it.

[image]
Source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-2/ammeter-usage/

You may not be able to tell the difference between an open circuit (if a switch is off) and if there isn't anything connected to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Do you know of any small circuits or chips that will measure the current flow , it will need to handle up to 9A at 12V

Comment: @jackveasey12333 did you look at the links, there are plenty of devices there, shopping recommendations are off topic here. I don't know what will work exactly for you application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a MOSFET to enable/disable charging. Every once in a while, close the MOSFET and check the battery voltage: if it's zero, then there's in fact no battery connected.

Either avoid doing this test while running without external voltage, or make sure your circuit will remain powered via the MOSFET's body diode even when it's closed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQxm3b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>